# Pass json data in console log to html

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, fetch, fetch-api

I am trying to pass json array data that I get in console log to div inside my html, but my code isn't returning any data. What could be the problem?

```js
let fetchRes = fetch("https://avax.dev/data/validators.json"); 
    // fetchRes is the promise to resolve // it by using.then() method 
fetchRes
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((d) => { 
    let len = d.validators.length; 
    console.log(len); 
    document.getElementById('len').innerHTML = len;
   })
   .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working, & it's showing the `len` also, I have created a `codeSnippet` please have a look

```js
let fetchRes = fetch("https://avax.dev/data/validators.json"); 
//fetchRes is the promise to resolve // it by using.then() method 
fetchRes.then((res) => res.json()).then((d) => { 
  let len = d.validators.length; 
  console.log(len); 
  document.getElementById('len').innerHTML=len;
}).catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
})
```

```html
<div id="len"></div>
```